# Combining ±% with ±dB in measurement uncertainty

Tags: measurement

Firstly apologies if this is not the correct place to post this but wasn't sure which site would be good to ask regarding about measurement uncertainty calculation.

I am trying to calculate the combined measurement uncertainty, however the uncertainties I want to combine are using different scales:

Carrier level uncertainty: ±0.5dB (logarithmic)

Modulation uncertainty: ±5% (linear)

Converting either from one format to another will not give me a simple ±value in the other format

What is the best way to combine these uncertainties

Comment: You have two parameters stated, what's the third (combined) meant to be? At the moment you have eggs and bacon but it sounds like you want to combine eggs and bacon into one parameter. Also, why is the word "uncertainty" used? Normally I'd use "tolerance"

Comment: Are you measuring power or amplitude?

Comment: Not an answer. A question related (to The Photon's answer). This is about a noise level in dB. If the uncertainty is ±0.5dB, the measured noise level is 100dB, does that mean the true value is in between 89dB and 112dB? Or, if not what is the range? Also if the measured value is 50dB, what is the range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind that one scale is logarithmic and the other is linear. Both error specs indicate ratios. I'll assume you're measuring power in some form.

Then an error of +/- 0.5 dB indicates the true value is between 0.89x and 1.12x what you measured (with whatever certainty is assumed by your definition of uncertainty).

And an error of +/- 5% indicates the value is between 0.95x and 1.05x what you measured.

If both uncertainties apply to the same measurement, you can multiply these ratios together and find the overall range is 0.846x to 1.178x the measurement, or that the overall error is +17.8% / -15.4% or +0.71 / -0.62 dB.

If you're measuring amplitudes rather than powers, of course you'll need to convert between dB and ratios differently.

Comment: based on what you said shouldn't the overall error work out to +17.8% / -15.4% or +0.71dB / -0.62dB

Comment: @kewsvnet, good point. Edited.